# Find an equivalent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

Consider $ u_n = (n+1)^{1/n+1} - n^{1/n} $

Find an equivalent sequence at infinity. (meaning $ u_n / y_n \rightarrow 1 ) $

I tried doing :

$ u_n = e^{ \frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1}}(1 - e^{\frac{ln(n)}{n} - \frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1} } )   $

Then $ \frac{ln(n)}{n} - \frac{ln(n+1)}{n+1} = \frac{ -1 + o(1) + ln(n)}{n(n+1)} $

How do I get a simple equivalent? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent sequences? Do you mean $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$?

Comment: I mean $ x_n / y_n  \rightarrow 1 $

A taylor approximation of degree 1 for example.

Comment: Thank you monadologie for your answer. May the monads bless you : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
u_n &= \exp(\frac{\ln(1+n)}{1+n}) - \exp(\frac{\ln(n)}{n})\\
&=  \exp(\frac{\ln(1+n)}{1+n})(1 -  \exp(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}-\frac{\ln(1+n)}{1+n}))\\
\end{align}
With
$$
1 -  \exp(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}-\frac{\ln(1+n)}{1+n}) \sim \frac{\ln(1+n)}{1+n} - \frac{\ln(n)}{n}
$$
and
$$
\exp(\frac{\ln(1+n)}{1+n}) \sim 1
$$
we get
$$
u_n \sim \frac{\ln(1+n)}{1+n} - \frac{\ln(n)}{n}.
$$
Also, you can develop further and see that
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(1+n)}{1+n} - \frac{\ln(n)}{n} \sim \frac{1-\ln(n)}{n^2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Try $y_n=n$.  We have $$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}{u_n\over y_n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}{(n+1)^{1/n+1} - n^{1/n}\over n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}{n+1\over n}(n+1)^{\frac1n}-{n^{1/n}\over n}\\
&= 1\cdot 1-0\\&=1
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}-n^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{n}\left(\frac{(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}}{n^{1/n}}-1\right)$$
Take $v_n=\left(\frac{(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}}{n^{1/n}}-1\right)$.
Then $\frac{u_n}{v_n}=\sqrt[n]{n}\to1$.